# Text book / online resource for learning to program at system/kernel level

Tags: operating-system, kernel

Is there any book/resource that one can refer to, to be able to write programs at kernel/system level.. I'm looking for a programming book that could serve as a guide to write kernel codes / system level programming etc..
I have Tannenbaum's Design and Implementation. It addresses theoretical aspects well .But a book that teaches programming in such topics would be helpful. I want to be capable of implementing thread library, scheduler et al ..

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest both the books by Robert Love. I've read a bit of the first one and its excellent. The latter was recommended by a friend.

[Linux Kernel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672327201)

[Linux System Programming: Talking Directly to the Kernel and C Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009585)

Answer (score 2):

There is one good website by the Technical editor of Book Linux Kernel Development,
Robert P J Day (he is different from Robert Love)
and the website is
http://crashcourse.ca/introduction-linux-kernel-programming/introduction-linux-kernel-programming
Once you are done with above link I would suggest to go through 
http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux
and then there is a Kernel Newbies mailing list.You should subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the nice "[Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000028/)" by O'Reilly. While Linux-specific sometimes, the basic concepts are the same everywhere.

Comment: You should consider upvoting comments that have helped you.